# Differentiable structure on $S^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds

How to show that the claim that there is exactly one differentiable structure on $S^4$ implies the smooth four-dimensional Poincaré conjecture (homotopy equivalent to $S^4$ implies diffeomorphic to $S^4$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $M$ is a closed smooth four-manifold homotopy equivalent to $S^4$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^4$. This follows from Freedman's Theorem.

> **Theorem (Freedman):** For any unimodular form $b$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, there is a closed simply connected topological four-manifold whose intersection form is isomorphic to $b$. If $b$ is even, the manifold is unique up to homeomorphism, while if $b$ is odd, there are two such manifolds (which are distinguished by their [Kirby-Siebenmann invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby%E2%80%93Siebenmann_class)).

The Kirby-Siebenmann invariant is the obstruction to admitting a PL structure. As a smooth structure induces a PL structure, smooth manifolds have vanishing Kirby-Siebenmann invariant. Therefore, we obtain the following:

> **Corollary:** Two closed smooth simply connected four-manifolds are homeomorphic if and only if they have isomorphic intersection forms.

If $M$ is a closed smooth simply connected four-manifold homotopy equivalent to $S^4$, then it has intersection form zero. But $S^4$ is another closed smooth simply connected four-manifold with intersection form zero, so by the above, $M$ is homeomorphic to $S^4$ (the topological four-dimensional Poincaré conjecture). That is, $M$ can be viewed as the topological manifold $S^4$ with a choice of smooth structure. If $S^4$ were to admit only one smooth structure up to diffeomorphism, then $M$ would be diffeomorphic to $S^4$ (the smooth four-dimensional Poincaré conjecture).

Comment: Respected Michael Albanese, Could you explain in simple terms. I am new in this field

Comment: Freedman's theorem tells you that a closed four-manifold homotopy equivalent to $S^4$ is in fact homeomorphic to $S^4$, so if the smooth four-dimensional Poincaré conjecture were false, there would be a smooth four-manifold homeomorphic to $S^4$ but not diffeomorphic to it, i.e. there would be a non-standard smooth structure on $S^4$.