# Extension of Smooth function to $\mathbb{R}^4 \cup \{\infty\}$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, quaternions, spheres, smooth-functions

Suppose we have a function $f(q) = q^2$ defined over the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$.

How does one formally show that the function $f$ defines on $\mathbb{R}^4 \cup \{\infty\} \cong S^4$ is smooth without specifying a smooth manifold structure on $\mathbb{R}^4 \cup \{\infty\}$ first?

On $\mathbb{R}^4$, $f$ clearly is a polynomial and therefore smooth. We only need a smooth extension to a "pole" on $S^4$. To show continuity, one could argue that as $\vec{x} \to \infty$, $\lvert f(\vec{x}) \rvert = \lvert \vec{x} \rvert^2 \to \infty$, and thus $f(\vec{x}) \to \infty$, but thus defining $f(\infty) = \infty$ would make the extension continuous. This is rather informal however. To show smoothness, I am stuck.

Thanks for any hints or solutions!

Comment: There is only one smooth structure on $\mathbb S^4$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741040/differentiable-structure-on-s4))

Comment: @ArcticChar, that is very interesting! So now that we have an unambiguous smooth structure on $S^4$ and therefore $\mathbb(R)^4 \cup \infty$, there must surely be a way to conclude that the map $f$ is smooth without going through coordinate chart computations, or? How would this be done?

Comment: I would say using coordinates chart is the easiest way, no? Any reason you don't want to do that?

Comment: I tried to come up with an atlas but always failed to show that my maps are homeomorphic on $\mathbb{R}^4 \cup \infty$. My initial idea was something like $\phi : \vec{x} \mapsto \vec{x}$ for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4, \lvert \vec{x} \rvert \lt 2$ and $\psi : \vec{x} \mapsto \frac{\vec{x}}{\lvert \vec{x} \rvert^2}$ for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^4, \lvert \vec{x} \rvert \gt 1$ and $\psi : \infty \mapsto 0$, but the inverse of $\psi$ fails to be continuous, at least with the topology I was using at the time